# Что значит в фильтре вопросов выбор сортировки - "Наиболее частые"?

Tags: поддержка, список-вопросов, фильтрация-вопросов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наиболе частые **что**? Отвечаемые, задаваемые? Просматриваемые - точно нет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[What's the 'Frequent' sort function?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172728/260198)

> Когда многие вопросы закрываются как дубликаты одного конкретного вопроса, этот вопрос является «частым» вопросом, т.е. его часто задавали в разных формах. Кроме того, если вопрос связан с другим вопросом (если он присутствует в списке похожих вопросов у других вопросов), он относится к числу часто задаваемых вопросов.

Comment: Ага, спасибо! В ссылке выше _If you hover over the tab, the tooltip is "questions with the most links"_ - уже устарело, сейчас там - "Frequent Questions".

Comment: У нас Frequent переведено где-то "Цитируемые", где-то "Частые": https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Frequent Может привести к одному виду? "Цитируемые" тут вроде лучше подходит.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight если это одно и то же, то да, хорошо бы к одному виду привести.

Comment: Как минимум в части случаев одно и то же. Создал вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10190/