# Перевод Frequent несогласован

Tags: дефект, локализация

Frequent (в отношении вопросов) у нас в разных местах [переведено по разному](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Frequent): где-то "Цитируемые", где-то "Частые". Например:

> [image: frequent]

---

> [image: most frequent]

Однако, в обоих случаях оно значит одно и тоже, сортировку по количеству ссылок на вопрос. Необходимо выбрать термин и использовать его во всех строках, где оно используется в этом значении.

Для наглядности текущее состояние переводов:

> [image: Frequent]

Связанный вопрос: [Что значит в фильтре вопросов выбор сортировки - "Наиболее частые"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10182/)

Comment: А мне оба не нравятся. Может ещё что придумать?

Comment: @Qwertiy а чем "цитируемые" не нравится? Очень даже научный (технический) термин. Но вот перевод вида "Часто задаваемые вопросы", я бы, наверное, не стал менять. Все же это довольно устоявшийся термин.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ "Часто спрашиваемые вопросы" (:

Answer (score 1):

Я бы оставил везде "частый вопрос". Или "Часто задаваемый вопрос" по трем причинам:

1. Это [дословный перевод](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/frequent+question).
2. По-русски так тоже говорят.
3. Цитируемый от слова цитировать, то есть приводить **дословную выдержку** от куда-то, желательно, с указанием источника. Если вопрос похожий, он частый, но не цитируемый.

> ЦИТИ'РОВАТЬ, рую, руешь, несов. (к процитировать), кого-что. Ссылаясь, приводить цитату из кого-н. (какого-н. автора) из чего-н. (какого-н. сочинения). В речи своей цитировал несколько мыслей из этой статьи. Достоевский. Ц. Пушкина.

Источник «Толковый словарь русского языка» под редакцией Д. Н. Ушакова (1935-1940).

> книжн. приводить цитату, то есть дословную выдержку из какого-либо текста

Источник : [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Если дословный перевод не нравится по каким-то причинам, то такие вопросы можно обозвать популярными. Думаю, это близко по смыслу и в достаточной мере отражает суть англоязычного термина.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать во всех случаях **Цитируемые**.

По мне, данный вариант больше подходит, хоть это и не дословный перевод.

Comment: Глядя на таблицу текущих переводов использование "Цитируемые" везде не видится мне таким уж однозначным вариантом.

Answer (score -7):

Востребованные.

---